# Menu Drawer implementation android

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

Hi I am trying to implement a sliding drawer overlay in my android app. I have taken reference from this link:

https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer

and implemented a menu drawer in my activity. So my activity has 2 fragments in a viewPager with a TitlePageIndicator. When I click on a button in the fragment, the menu drawer opens. Currently the drawer overlays the titlePageIndicator as well. I would like to know to implement a menu drawer which opens/overlays below the title of the viewPager. Or is something like that not possible? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below xml, you should define a layout below of your titlebar and set that for it:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mhp.chek"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- main layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/base_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- for example your **viewpager** can define here -->

</LinearLayout>

<!-- drawer layout-->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

note that you need support library for this one.